# Изменение видимости объекта при нажатии

Tags: flash

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на объект видимость другого объекта изменялась, и также при наведении мышки. Flash CS 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
spr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hide);
spr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, hide);
function hide(event:MouseEvent):void{ spr2.visible = false;}
```